# Node JS serving html file with css

Tags: html, css, node.js, http

I'm practicing pure node js and i've encountred a thing that disturb about http protocole.
I finally served my html page with css after an hour or so of searching and testing my code. Here is my code :

```
const server = http.createServer((req, res)=>{
if(req.url === "/"){
    fs.readFile("index.html", "UTF-8", function(err, data){
        res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
        res.end(data);
    });
}else if(req.url === "/styles.css")){
    var cssPath = path.join(__dirname, 'public', req.url);
    var fileStream = fs.createReadStream(cssPath, "UTF-8");
    res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/css"});
    fileStream.pipe(res);
};
});
```

But I didn't understand why it works. Well I've only typed "/" in the browser, I didn't type "/styles.css". And why I don't see "/styles.css" in the URL bar.
I'm sure it's because of how the http protocole is  designed but can you help with some explanation of this protocole.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: You have a typo!

Second closing bracket in  ... else if(req.url == "/styles.css")) is extra!

Comment: Oh thank you, i didn't pay attention while replacing the code

Answer (score 0):

If you had typed `/styles.css` in the address bar, then you would see the source code the CSS file. For example: [this link](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/primary.css?v=337f2af46405).

You type `/`, then the browser asks the server to `/` and the server responds with an HTML document.

Then the browser renders the HTML document. The HTML document, I assume, includes something like:

```
<link rel=stylesheet href=/styles.css>
```

So the browser asks the server for `/styles.css` and the server responds with a CSS file. The browser then applies that CSS to the HTML document.

It doesn't show `/styles.css` in the address bar because you are looking at `/`. The CSS file is just a different resource that is needed to fully render the HTML document that `/` represents.